# Как сделать State в ECS архитектуре?

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, архитектура, state, ecs

Хочу реализовать классическую для ECS задачу, как в RPG игре Dungeon Siege: юнит стоит, бежит, атакует, взаимодействует с сундуком/рычагом, валяется мертвым и т.д.

В классическом ООП это просто паттерн state, но как он выглядит в ECS архитектуре? Я не понимаю как может существовать контракт `current state` в виде компонентов на сущности (энтити), что он всегда один, что их не два или не ноль. Вариант что, `CurrentStateType` это поле в `UnitModel` и все системы обрабатывающие каждый стейт, чекает его, видится рабочим, но это как клиенты долбящие запросами сервер http чата, криповая кринжуха какая-то. А как это делать по людски?

Comment: `current state` может быть не отдельным компонентом, а вычисляемой функцией от нескольких других компонентов.

Comment: @Kromster Стейтов не больше десяти, на каждого юнита, которых тоже не очень много и в целом нагрузка не значительная, сотня простых ифов за апдейт любое современное устройство особо не напрядет, но блин, это же все равно уродливая архитектура.

Comment: @ESkri, типа `UnitModelReferenceComponent`, `MoveComponent`, `IsMovingTagComponent`, но где нерушимый контракт, что тег всегда один и стейт машина не съедит с рельс?

Comment: @tym32167 Entity Component System, часто применяется в геймдеве.

Comment: @Kromster понял, спасибо

Comment: @tym32167 Entity - `GameObject` (на сцене), Component - его компоненты, например привязанный к нему `RigidBody`, придающий физическое поведение, System - сам движок, а точнее согласно термину его часть, например гравитация, реализация физики. То есть систем в том же Unity несколько.

Comment: @aepot да, я понял, что это что то либо относительно новое, либо специфичное для платформ для разраотки игр типа Юнити. Я просто когда то лет 20 назад очень интересовался разработкой игр, но этот акроним не припонмю. Спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: @tym32167 Это асболютно не специфическая вещь, хотя в играх наверное используется сильно чаще. ООП это `object-oriented programming`, а ECS ломает парадигму, потому что он `data-oriented design`. Вроде все на объектах, но классы лишь обработчики без данных, нет инкапсуляции, полиморфизма и наследования, архитектура построена на обработках моделей данных в сущностях.

Comment: @aepot, `Unity` не это ECS, `Component` на `GameObject` это не данные сущности, а полноценные, привычные нам классы, унаследованные от `MonoBehaviour`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Вопрос несколько туманен в том, какое именно Состояние имеется ввиду. Это состояние Машины Состояний или это флаг чего-либо (на каждый чих по флагу - ведь тоже подход). Также непонятен сценарий использования, это обработка состояний при апдейтах внутренних процессов или часть Управления от игрока (почти одно и то же) или Презентации в интерфейс.*

**Данный ответ про Машину Состояний и внутренние апдейты.*

---

По-хорошему, при любом раскладе, если состояние всегда одно и однозначно, то и SPOT у него должен быть один (Single Point Of Truth), чтобы не было по как-то причинам рассинхрона, что одни компоненту думают, что юнит бежит, а другие - что он уже умер.

Единое состояние надо где-то хранить или вычислять. Т.е. Предоставлять "наружу" геттер. Это может быть как свойство юнита, так и отдельный компонент. По сути, State ничем не отличается от, например, положения юнита в мире - точно такое же нерушимо-однозначное свойство.

Если сделаете компонентом, то можете в него положить какие-то доп.свойства нужные для расчета Машины Состояний (и, соответственно, сделать итератор который будет все состояния апдейтить). Например, длительность текущего состояния, чтобы автоматом переводить умирающего в мертвого, или мертвого в разложившегося.

И на всякий случай, взять значение атрибута по прямой ссылке (или даже через 2-3) совершенно не то же самое, что делать и ждать HTTP запрос, порядков так на 5-7 (доли нс против десятков мс). Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией =)

Comment: Ну короче, именно то чего я не хотел) Десять систем каждый апдейт как стая налетает начиная c строчки: Я? а? я? яЯ? Не? ну чё? и это латырея лишь с одним победителем...

Comment: @Yaroslav похоже у вас искаженное восприятие о том, что является затратными операциями, а что нет - это не HTTP, не клиент-сервер, это скорее соседние килобайты памяти лежащие в одном L2 кэше.. Про лотерею с одним победителе не понял )

Comment: Нет, я все это знаю и понимаю, что это экономия на спичках, просто чувство прекрасного в архитектуре) Латырея это типа того что, только у одной системы обрабатывающей конкретный стейт в зависимости от типа поведения будет возможность поработать, но всем придется подойти к кассе с билетиком и спросить, мой ли счастливый час? И все кроме одного получат ответ "пшел нахер!". Я новечек в ECS. А с бекэндом я вообще особо не знаком, чисто фронтэнд, но в курсе, что до вебсокетов, чаты работали так, безконца стучась к серверу с вопросом о новых постах)

Comment: @Yaroslav эхх, это тяжелое травматическое детство, деревянные игрушки прибитые к полу .. )) Как вариант, если весь компонент при каких-то состояниях становится невалиден и не нужен, то можете его просто отключить. Т.е. если юнит безвозвратно мертв, то удаляем все его компоненты, кроме тех, что нужны для рисовалки тела. Это может быть и внутри компонента тоже - типа "если юнит мертв, то самоудалиться". Но ключевое тут - **экономия на спичках**. Сделайте нормально, а потом уже запрофилируете и заоптимизируете.